# XPath Error - The default (no prefix) Namespace URI for XPath queries is always ''

Tags: xml, xpath

I have XML in this example format:

```
<ExternalEvent xmlns="http://www.redeyedmonster.co.uk/Integration/ESB">
    <EventType>Create</EventType>
    <Message>SomeMessage</Message>
    <ServiceRequestId>75a144b8-5a11-e311-bd23-0050569f00cc</ServiceRequestId>
    <SourceSystem>MySource</SourceSystem>
</ExternalEvent>
```

and I am stuck with it.

I am trying to evaluate the value of the EventType node.  I have tried:

```
/ExternalEvent/EventType
```

and

```
/*[local-name() = 'ExternalPath' and *[local-name() = 'EventType']]
```

and

```
/*[local-name()='ExternalEvent' and namespace-uri()='http://www.redeyedmonster.co.uk/Integration/ESB']/*[local-name()='EventType' and namespace-uri()='http://www.redeyedmonster.co.uk/Integration/ESB']
```

plus many other variations.  However in [XPath Tester](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) I always get the same error which is:

> The default (no prefix) Namespace URI for XPath queries is always '' and it cannot be redefined to 'http://www.redeyedmonster.co.uk/Integration/ESB'.

If I remove the namespace phrase (xmlns="http://www.redeyedmonster.co.uk/Integration/ESB") from the XML then I am able to evaluate the value of event type no problem but unfortunately I am stuck with XML in this format and it cannot be changed for my solution.

Is there a way round this?  As I believe it may be the the underlying cause of a routing problem I have in my ESB solution.

Comment: Your last option should work fine, but the usual way to deal with namespaces in XPath is to bind the URI to a prefix and then use that prefix in the expressions (e.g. `/esb:ExternalEvent/esb:EventType`).  Exactly how you declare prefix bindings varies between different XPath engines - what tool or library are you using to execute these XPath expressions?

Comment: That error message appears to be a limitation of the tester you're using rather than a problem with the expression you're trying to test.

Comment: I am actually trying to resolve this within a BizTalk ESB Messaging Broker Extender that doesn't appear to want to play :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to get the node by using the expression to directly get `EventType` data like `[//*local-name()='EventType']` or you can even try something like `[/*localname()='ExternalPath'/*local-name()='EventType']` don't use and.