# Why does this Selenium/XPath query select only the first `g` tag?

Tags: selenium, xpath, svg

I have an `svg` element with multiple `g` tags inside it. Typically, when I select a tag by name, I get a list of all tags on the page. For example, this returns a list of Selenium `WebElement` instances:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a')
```

But when I try to select all the `g` tags inside my `svg` element, I only get the first element returned. For example:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]')
```

And here my markup:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>...</g>
    <g>...</g>
    <g>...</g>
    ...
</svg>
```

How can I select all the `g` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That because you used `find_element_by_xpath` which returns the first element. To return all the elements then use `find_elements_by_xpath`:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]')
```

But I would use a CSS selector which is shorter:

```
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('svg > g')
```

Comment: I don't agree the CSS locator is shorter.  They are typically usually the same length when written correctly: `.//svg/g`

Comment: @djangofan, your statement would be true if ".//svg/g" was working, but it's not.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would do it:

With the following XML:

```
...
<svg>
    <g>1</g>
    <g>2</g>
    <g>3</g>
</svg>
...
```

Then use this XPath expression:

```
 //svg/g
```

This will return 3 nodes, as shown on this site: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

NOTE1: If you introduce the namespace on the `svg` tag, you will see this error from the above site: `The default (no prefix) Namespace URI for XPath queries is always '' and it cannot be redefined to 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'.`

NOTE2: Another similar question here: [XPath Error - The default (no prefix) Namespace URI for XPath queries is always ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530625/xpath-error-the-default-no-prefix-namespace-uri-for-xpath-queries-is-always)

Comment: That XPath expression was the first one I tried, but it did not return any elements. I got the `name()="svg"` snippet from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592213/